# Transitioning from Rails 2 to Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created/worked on tons of webapps with Rails 1/2 about 5 years back, then I have been working solely on pure Ruby/other non-Rails projects, so (barring a hobby app I wrote in Rails 3, mostly Rails 2 style) I was out of the loop totally.

What resources (books, videos, blogs etc.) would you recommend to get up to speed with Rails 4 - obviously I'm not looking for beginner stuff, but rather best practices/features etc. that have been added since Rails 2 - for example base apps, engines, metal/rack, testing changes etc. (yeah, I have been living in a cave for this long - these are some examples of things that started to appear when I 'quit').

(Maybe the title is a bit misleading: I'm not actually looking to turn/upgrade an existing Rails 2 app into a Rails 4 one, but rather to educate myself about the new stuff before starting a new one)

Comment: This is not related to code then :)

Answer (score 1):

These links will help to know more about rails 3 and 4..

http://rails4.codeschool.com/videos

http://railscasts.com/?type=free

Answer (score 0):

I really like the Rails Way series.  I think it's very good at explaining the intended use of the new features in the updated version of Rails.

You can see the rails 4 way here:

[http://www.amazon.com/Rails-Addison-Wesley-Professional-Ruby-Series/dp/0321944275/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1377676159&sr=8-1&keywords=the+rails+4+way](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321944275)

My library had an online copy as well, so you might want to check for that.  I think it's a huge advantage to have an electronic version so that you can copy and paste code easily.